How to parse in Postman body response from XML format
Using POST request in Postmat I received a body response as XML data like this.
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <S:Body>
            <ns2:getAuthenticationTokenResponse xmlns:ns2="http://some_url.com" xmlns:ns3="http://some_url.com">
                <return>111222333</return>
            </ns2:getAuthenticationTokenResponse>
        </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>

And I need to get somehow value 111222333 as a collection variable. And I'm lost with solution since I have no experience with JS before. Please provide me with some solution.

I was debating on whether to provide an answer to this question, as you haven't shown any attempt to solve this yourself.  Saying "I have no experience with JS, so please provide me with a a solution" is not normally going to get you much of a response.

What's JS,  and what's the connection with XML? Please provide me with an answer!

Can you isolate the problem by creating an MRE?

maybe xml2js can resolve your question.
this is sample code:
const xml2js = require('xml2js');   
xml2js.parseString(pm.response.text(), function (err, result) {
    console.log(result);
});


xml2js is available in the Postman sandbox and gives you a lot more control over the output.
You are basically converting the XML to a JavaScript Object.
For example…
// step 1 - parse XML\Soap response 
const xmlResponse = pm.response.json();

// step 2 - parse the XML test to JSON - so its easier to work with
let parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;
const stripPrefix = require('xml2js').processors.stripPrefix;

parseString(xmlResponse, {
    tagNameProcessors: [stripPrefix],
    ignoreAttrs: true,
    explicitArray: false,
}, function (err, jsonData) {
    // handle any errors in the XML
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        // do something with the result
        console.log(jsonData.Envelope.Body.getAuthenticationTokenResponse.return); // 111222333
    }
});

It depends on how complex your XML is, but have a look here (scroll to the bottom) for all of the formatting options.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml2js

Thank you very much for such detailed solution version! It is extremely helpful.

I'm really appreciate for all who give me help with this topic. My final version of solution is looks like this:
//
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
console.log(xml2js);
//

Just enter "111222333" into your collection variable

Thank you for an idea. Manual input it is what I did at first stage. But this token is a fast changing thing. So it is better to have more automatized token extract process.

I'm really appreciate for all who give me help with this topic. Final version of solution is looks like this:
    const xml2js = require('xml2js');
    
    // taking XML response  
    const responseBody = pm.response.text();
    
    //parsing XML body 
    xml2js.parseString(responseBody, { explicitArray:
    false }, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {console.error("Error parsing XML:", err);} 
    else {
    //Taking Token
    const tokenValue = result['S:Envelope']['S:Body']['ns2:getAuthenticationTokenResponse']['return'];

    // Bringing Token to a collection variable
    pm.collectionVariables.set("a_Token", tokenValue);
    console.log("Extracted Token Value: ", tokenValue);
} });


Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient. Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?
